# How to generate a collinear point without revealing one of the existed two points?

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

Assume we have point $A(x_A,y_A)$ and point $B(x_B,y_B)$, and now we want to generate a point $C(x_C,y_C)$ so that $A,B,C$ are on the same straight line. All mod $p$.

If $A$ or $B$ could not be revealed, how to do that? Could homomorphic encryption help? I learned about BGN, but I think it is useless because there're two multiply there, that is:

$y_C=\frac{(y_A-y_B)(x_C-x_B)}{x_A-x_B}$

Comment: How do you want to generate $C$?  If it's randomly, the obvious way is to pick a random secret $k$, and reveal $x_C = k x_A + (1 - k) x_B, y_C = k y_A + (1 - k) y_B$

Comment: @poncho I mean, $x_B$ and $y_B$ should not be revealed. For example, $A$ and $B$ are held by different party, $A$ want to generate a random $C$ without knowing the plaintext of point $B$.